# Accessing values from i2c address

Tags: c, memory, i2c

You can take a look at this website: http://www.hitechnic.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=NSK1042 to get a better understanding of what I'm talking about. For example, the website reads: the i2c address of the sensor is 0x10 and the table of the values there reads:

```
Address       Type           Contents

00 – 07H      chars           Serial Version Number

43H           byte            Sensor 1 DC Signal Strength
```

How can I access these values in C? Thanks.

Comment: i2c is a protocol for communicating with external hardware.  There is no native support in C for i2c.  You would need to use a library or roll your own.  Did you Google?  What processor are you using?  What C compiler?  Without those details the question may be closed.  Please don't refer people to links, better include the relevant information in the question.  These are people volunteering their time to help you, make their life easy to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These registers can be memory mapped. A few things you'll need to do:

- map the device's physical memory to your programs address space
- declare any pointers to this region as volatile

The volatile keyword will stop the compiler from "optimizing" the program to be incorrect. e.g. by assuming that reads to the same memory location will yield the same result because the program hasn't written to it.

The easy part of this is to declare a struct such that all the offsets are the same as the device and that each part has the right size.

ie

```
struct hitech {
    char serial_version[8];
    char manufacturer[8];
    /* etc */
};

volatile struct hitech *my_device;
```

The second part is working out where the device is mapped. If it's plugged in to your computer you should be able to see this. You might need to do one of the following: mmap the device's physical address. Or just write my_device = 0x< address >. Or a combination of the two.

From the website:
"The I2C address of the IRSeeker V2 sensor is 0x10"

So you want to write 0x10 above for my_device.

Then you'll need to compile for the correct micro-controller and load your program at the correct location as firmware.

You'd be better off using their programming language.

Comment: dave: how do you know that these can be memory mapped on the OPs machine?

Comment: @Guy Sirton Because it's strongly suggested by the website. It could be wrong though. If it is mapped then he should be able to see this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're not supplying an SDK for you to access these values:

```
// I'm assuming these are read-only, hence the "const"
const char *g_serialVersionNumber = (const char *)0x00; // be careful not to access more than 8 bytes
const unsigned char *g_sensor1DCSignalStrength = (const unsigned char *)0x43;

void main()
{
    printf("Serial version number: %s\n", g_serialVersionNumber);
    printf("Sensor 1 DC Signal Strength: %d\n", *g_sensor1DCSignalStrength);
}
```

Comment: Why are you assuming the i2c addresses are memory mapped to the process address space?  This is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: This will certainly segmentation fault. Address 0x0 is kernel memory and you can't access that.

Comment: Given that I'm not familiar with the device, if they don't supply an SDK, there is really no other conclusion to come to. However, I would imagine an SDK is supplied (hence the "assuming they're not...").

Comment: @dave: maybe there's no kernel?

Comment: @JimBuck: If there's no SDK you may need to write a driver or access some memory mapped I/O... Regardless your code is almost certainly wrong, it would be highly unusual (not to say impossible) that i2c addresses are mapped in this fashion.

Comment: Yeah, I've no idea. I just posted code that generally is meant to access hardcoded addresses. This is what we did in the PlayStation1 days. If this applies to this device, great. If not, he'll know the moment he compiles/runs/segfaults. :)